# How to customize rails file upload form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 6 activestorage to upload photos. I would like to customize the look and feel of the file upload button (with Bulma css framework). I have tried these:

```rb
        <div class="file" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <label class="file-label">
        <span class="file-cta">
        <span class="file-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
        </span>
        <%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true, direct_upload: true, class:" ", placeholder:"", style:"" %>

        </span>
        </label>
        </div>







                <div class="file" style="    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;">
        <label class="file-label">
        <span class="file-cta">
        <span class="file-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
        </span>
        <%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true, direct_upload: true, class:" ", placeholder:"Choose files", style:"    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);" %>
        <span class="file-label">
        Choose photos
        </span>

        </span>
        </div>
```

The first shows the one on the top (photo below) and the second the bottom one.

[image]

The problem with the first one is that "Choose Files" rails default upload button is within the Bulma upload button.

The problem with the second is that once I upload photos, I no longer see the name of the files that have been uploaded.

What can I do? I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in a div, and make the div position: relative.
then you can male the form field position: absolute then style the div instead of the form field